# How to offer services when organization is looking for an Employee

Tags: consulting

I am an independent contractor and recently saw a job posting for the same work I do as a contractor. I do not want to be an employee but would like the organization to know that I specialize in that type of work.
How do I approach the organization about my services? By the way they have an immediate need.
I'm thinking I should introduce my company and services and ask for a meeting.

Comment: Can't hurt to try. It would probably help to emphasize all the "savings" they get by not hiring a new employee - benefits, insurance, matching taxes, HR department paperwork to process new employees, loss of productivity from someone else having to train the new employee, regular review meetings, etc. Add to that the benefits of a contractor - no long-term commitment, payments based on performance, all the tools to do the tasks are operational and configured for maximum productivity, etc. Create a proposal, formally, and present it to them. The practice can be good, even if it don't work.

Comment: Thanks Gypsy Spellweaver for your response! I applied for the job and they contacted me back within the hour. I have my interview tomorrow and I will present my consulting services and hope all goes well. This is definitely taking me out of my comfort zone but the practice will do me good.

Comment: Go get 'em! You're future awaits. :D

Answer (score 1):

One way to spin the 1099 vs FTE is to mention that you aren't interested in being an FTE but if they are having a difficult time filling that role with an FTE that you can fill that need temporarily to meet the business need until they do find an FTE.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the contact information of multiple clients and start off by creating an email list. Try to email or call them and let them know that you are a contractor, etc. Then build a good relationship with them, network with other contractors, and offer your services. Even if they are not interested on the spot, when the opportunity arises, they will think about you and contact you when they need a contractor. You can also put up your services on LinkedIn or job sites and get yourself known.

Comment: In other words you would become a spammer.  Apart from being a criminal offence in many jurisdictions, you would pretty much guarantee being blacklisted.